# flutter_downloader In the release version, it crashes (on Android)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-downloader

I use flutter_downloader (on Android)
Everything is correct in debug and profile mode and works well, but in the release version, after hitting the download button, the program crashes and that's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary solution could be:

> **@pragma('vm:entry-point')** must be placed above the callback function
> to avoid tree shaking in release mode for Android.

[github](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/629#issuecomment-1110603778)